# Hidden Column in Sharepoint 2013 shows up in excel download

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 list where I hide a column "Incremental Number" on the list view but when I download the list it shows up in the excel download. I checked the modified view setting and the hidden column is checked off. How can I NOT show it in excel download? This Column-"Incremental Number" is used to create another column which is an ID column.

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The “Export to Excel” function is used to export all items in the current view. It means, the columns and items in the exported table are determined by the current list view. So make sure you have selected the correct view before exporting the list.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do you create a "TestView"?

Comment: Also this Column is used as a reference in another column as a calculated number

Comment: To create a view, go to list settings -> scroll down to "Views" section -> Click "Create view"

Comment: I created a new view but the download still shows the hidden column. Any other suggestions?